# How to split email id in java

Tags: java

While splitting an email id getting this massage `[Ljava.lang.String;@776a35.`
            why i cant understand.

```
        String[] For_split_email=email.split("[@._]");
        for (int j = 0; j <= For_split_email.length - 1; j++) {
        System.out.println("splited emails----------"+For_split_email[j]);
         }
```

Comment: Split you are doing it with regx [@.] ?

Comment: show us the content of `email`.

Comment: Your output corresponds to printing an array of strings, but your code prints individual strings. Delete all compiled class files and rebuild everything.

Comment: @kai,  helen@sassybella.com  this is the content of email...

Comment: isyour code producing that unreadable message really printing out `For_split_email[j]` or it is simply `For_split_email` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is perfectly working for me. But it should be `j <= For_split_email.length - 1` in the for loop.

```
    String email = "test@test.de";
    String[] For_split_email = email.split("[@._]");
    for (int j = 0; j <= For_split_email.length - 1; j++)
    {
        System.out.println("splited emails----------" + For_split_email[j]);
    }
```

Output:

```
splited emails----------test
splited emails----------test
splited emails----------de
```

Comment: sorry it was like that . now i have edited my question. thanku for pointing me.

Answer (score 2):

In java, you can't print an array (that's the output you get when you try). You must use `Arrays.toString()`.

```
String[] For_split_email=email.split("[@._]");
System.out.println("splited emails----------"
    + Arrays.toString(For_split_email));
```

I'm pretty sure the code you posted isn't the code that produced that output.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
String str = "example@email.com";
String split_first = str.substring(0,str.indexOf("@"));
String split_second = str.substring(str.indexOf("@")+1);
```

or

```
String email = "example@email.com";
String[] For_split_email=email.split("[@|\\.|_]");
        for (int j = 0; j <= For_split_email.length - 1; j++) {
        System.out.println("splited emails----------"+For_split_email[j]);
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you given as the content of email.If you want to split the email as you mentioned in the question please try like this ,

```
    String email ="test@gmail.com";
    String[] For_split_email=email.split("[@._]");
    for (int j = 0; j <= For_split_email.length - 1; j++) {
       System.out.println("splited emails----------"+For_split_email[j]);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
String email = "raju@gamil.com";
String[] For_split_email = email.split("[@._]");
for (int j = 0; j <= For_split_email.length - 1; j++)
{
    System.out.println("splited emails data----------" + For_split_email[j]);
}
```